# NDSolve methods

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

In solving a large system of ODEs I found that `Method->ExplicitRungeKutta` (also `Automatic` as a matter of fact) is fast, but often unstable. I tried the option `Method->ImplicitRungeKutta`, but for the given number of ODEs (3924) the memory used by the kernel grows above 50GB. Eventually I have to stop the calculation. What options of `NDSolve` can be tried to improve the stability and remain with reasonable memory consumption?

Comment: Generally, implicit methods require a lot more work (and storage) per step, but if a problem is stiff (cf. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237989)), an implicit method will take fewer steps than an explicit method. Then, you have methods that are able to switch between using an explicit and implicit method (e.g. `"StiffnessSwitching"`), depending on the ODE's behavior. Without seeing what your ODEs look like, it's hard to say more.

Comment: @J.M. right, but as far as I understand, the `"StiffnessSwitching"` switches from explicit to implicit, but never goes back to explicit.

Comment: Actually it does; that's why it supports a `"NonstiffTest"` as well as a `"StiffnessTest"` option. See the discussion in [Stiffness Detection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html).

Comment: @J.M. Interesting, but after all it seems that implicit methods are too costly for my case.

Comment: Have you looked into whether `Method -> "Extrapolation"` suits your needs?

Comment: What do you mean by _unstable_? My personal experience is the default setting of `NDSolve` is quite robust for IVP of ODE(s). (There exist rare cases that one needs to adjust `MaxStepSize` though. ) But who knows… As @J.M. said, it's hard to advise without a concrete example.

Comment: @J.M. I looked into your suggestion. It did not solve my problem, but it useful in another respect, namely, it detects very well where exactly the system become unstable. Other methods delay the warning message to later times, which makes the analysis harder.

Comment: @xzczd `ExplicitRungeKutta` does not preserve some important properties, like number of particles. This has a strong impact on subsequent time-steps until all observables diverge. I suppose something similar happens in my case.

Comment: You can also use Picard iteration, you then start with trail functions for the solutions, insert those in the ODEs and integrate numerically. You then iterate this a number of times.  If $u_n$ is the nth iteration, you consider the series: $u = u_0 + (u_1-u_0)g + (u_2-u_1)g^2 +\cdots$ where you sum till the last iteration. The value for $g = 1$ is then your best approximation, but this may not be good enough, the series may even diverge. However, you can use resummation methods such as Pade approximants and then substitute $g = 1$.

Comment: @yarchik Did you read this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208590/numerically-solving-a-system-of-many-coupled-non-linear-odes-efficiently ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, I have seen this post before. I am not solving classical equations of motions, it is some kind of quantum dynamics with nonlinear terms. So, I do not know how to adapt the Verlet algorithms to this case.

Comment: @yarchik Is it superconducting model or quantum condensate?

Comment: @AlexTrounev No, it's the Hubbard model :)

Comment: @yarchik Did you read this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.02290.pdf ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you, I know some authors of the paper, but I have not seen the paper before.