# Stiff system problems with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I'm trying to solve the two order differential equations using NDSolve.
Here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Ω1 = 5; Ω2 = -2; m \
= 0.1109; g = 0.0089; timelimit = 10000;
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + x'[t] == 
     Sin[x[t] - Ω1 t] Exp[-y[t]] + 
      Sin[2 x[t] - Ω2 t] Exp[-2 y[t]], 
    m y''[t] + y'[t] == 
     Cos[Ω1 t - x[t]] Exp[-y[t]] + 
      Cos[Ω2 t - 2 x[t]] Exp[-2 y[t]] - g, x[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, timelimit}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, timelimit}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

The parameter of m and g is based on physical model. And the source in the right hand of the function is the product of Sin function and exponential function.

If I set `y[0] == 0`

It will illustrate that `` NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 3.0092307260023015`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected ``

If I changed the value of `y'[0]` to 1,2 or other values, or I add whenevent like this , this problems will be solved.

`WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> - y'[t]]}` .

But I don't know the basic mechanism.

LIke in what conditions it will show a stiff system. If I want to get the simulation results in that condition, what's the proper way to solve the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You tagged the question "singularity" but you say "stiff."  Which is it, stiffness or a singularity? Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39028/understanding-ndsolvendsz/237989#237989

Comment: Exponential function in the source term is a problem. The system diverges when y(t) becomes negative. Are you sure your equations are physically correct?

Comment: @ Michael E2 I thought singularity may lead to stiff system, so I added it. It may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, true. If I add whenevent and keep y[t]>0, this problem may be sovled

Answer (score 2):

It may help to look at

```
Plot[{x[t] /. s, y[t] /. s}, {t, 0,  Last[First[x["Domain"] /. First[s]]]}]
```

[image: x[t] in blue, y[y] in orange]

It appears that the derivatives are getting very steep.
Indeed, the plot

```
Plot[{x'[t] /. s, y'[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 
  Last[First[x["Domain"] /. First[s]]]}, PlotLegends -> {"x'", "y'"}]
```

[image: x'[t] and y'[t]]

suggests a singularity at around 3

Comment: Good point. Find singularity through output. What does this ```{t, 0, 
  Last[First[x["Domain"] /. First[s]]]}``` mean.

Comment: NDSolve returns InterpolatingFunctions, in this case x and y. They tell you the range over which they are defined. So, for example, x["Domain"]/.First[s] (the first here is because NDSolve returns a list of solutions, we want to look at the first --and I suspect only -- solution in that list) returns the domain {{from_t, to_t}}. Last[First[...]] returns to_t, the maximum t of the domain. Beyond that, the interpolating function relies on extrapolation.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks @JV3. Recently, I found that sometimes if I increase the total simulation time, it may run into the stiff system. Do you know why the total simulation time will have an effect on the final result?

Comment: Again, I'd recommend looking at the solution to see what's happening at the point where you run into trouble.