# Assistance with NDSolve error "At \[Tau] == 6.656861910808319`, step size is effectively zero; \ singularity or stiff system suspected"

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have been trying to simulate a nanocontinuum whose interaction is described by the modified Lennard-Jones potential. All of my other simulations worked perfectly, but I got stuck when I introduced a function of linear growth into the continuum. The nanocontinuum is described by a PDE which is converted and truncated to 150 coupled system of ODEs (using the numerical method of lines). I attached the entire code. Been struggling with this error for several months now. Would really appreciate suggestions, thoughts, and/or criticism. I am willing to provide further clarifications if my initial explanation was not helpful.

```
λ := 6.743; ω := 2.642; mt := -0.115; nt := -0.294; ϵ := 0.0315

rt := 3.001693; λλ := λ*rt; ωω := ω*rt; mass := 197; aa := (λλ^2*mt - ωω^2*mt + λλ*mt - ωω*nt - 2*λλ*ωω*nt)/mass; bb := (λλ^2*nt - ωω^2*nt + λλ*nt + ωω*mt + 2*λλ*ωω*mt)/mass; mlines := 150; h := mlines^(-1); R0 := -25*rt; U0 := 5

a := (11*aa)/(aa - bb)/h^2; b := -(bb/(aa - bb))/h^2; λs := (λλ*U0)/R0; ωs := (ωω*U0)/R0


PDE := D[Subscript[v, i][τ], τ, τ] - ((ϵ*i)/(1 + ϵ*τ))*D[Subscript[v, i + 1][τ] - Subscript[v, i - 1][τ], τ] - 
(((Subscript[v, i + 1][τ] - Subscript[v, i - 1][τ])/(2*h))^(-λs - 2)*(a*Cos[ωs*Log[(1/(1 + ϵ*τ))*((Subscript[v, i + 1][τ] - Subscript[v, i - 1][τ])/(2*h))]] + 
   b*Sin[ωs*Log[(1/(1 + ϵ*τ))*((Subscript[v, i + 1][τ] - Subscript[v, i - 1][τ])/(2*h))]])*(Subscript[v, i + 1][τ] - 2*Subscript[v, i][τ] + Subscript[v, i - 1][τ]))/(1/(1 + ϵ*τ))^λs == 0

Subscript[v, 0][τ] = 0; Derivative[1][Subscript[v, 0]][τ] = 0; Derivative[1][Subscript[v, mlines]][τ] = 2*h + Derivative[1][Subscript[v, mlines - 1]][τ]; 
Subscript[v, mlines][τ] = 2*h + Subscript[v, mlines - 1][τ]; PDEsystem = Table[PDE, {i, 1, mlines - 1}]; V[τ_] = Table[Subscript[v, i][τ], {i, 1, mlines - 1}]

initc1 = Table[Subscript[v, i][0] == 1*Sin[(Pi/2)*(i/mlines)], {i, 1, mlines - 1}]; 
initc2 = Table[Derivative[1][Subscript[v, i]][0] == 0, {i, 1, mlines - 1}]; time = 2500*Pi;

molsol = NDSolve[Join[PDEsystem, initc1, initc2], V[τ], {τ, 0, time}, Method -> "BDF"]; 
XX = molsol[[1,1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested link MarcoB, I will create a new question because there's no way I can edit the current question. Initially, I was directly copying the codes from the Mathematica notebook to the code block on this website. Hence, the fancy formatting. 

I have looked through some old posts, but they were not helpful. Unfortunately, the only way I know how to try to solve stiff systems is by changing the ODE solver, but this hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Thank you MarcoB, I was successfully able to update the code according to the instructions provided in the weblink. I hope the code works now.

Comment: The first thing to do is plot the solution and its derivative over the **computed solution interval**. (If it's a high dimensional system, plot the norm of the solution vector and the norm of its derivative.) If it looks like it's going to infinity, then it's a singularity and the singularity is a feature. If the system is unstable and every nearby solution develops a singularity, then it may be hard to solve. If you change the `WorkingPrecision` and the time that the singularity develops changes, then it may be this type. A true feature won't change when `WorkingPrecision` is increased.

Comment: If it is not a singularity (which is the more common explanation), then try `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.  This contains a somewhat theoretical discussion of stiffness and `NDSolve`, which may or may be helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39028/understanding-ndsolvendsz/237989#237989

Comment: Thank you @Michael... The solution plot and its derivative are both going to infinity. Changing the initial points makes the time of singularity change. Introducing WorkingPrecision doesn't really influence any change to the time of singularity.

I have tried `Method->"StiffnessSwitching"` it doesn't influence any change in the error. I will read through the thread for helpful guidance.