# Stiffness problem which abruptly stops the evaluation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, parametric-functions, stiffness

We have a Lagrangian and we found the EOM. We need to solve the EOM and find the Phase-space plot. However, we are facing a stiffness problem which abruptly stops the evaluation (`NDSolve::ndsz`). The `StiffnessSwitching` method seems to not work. We have tried  `{"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False, "TimeIntegration" -> "Extrapolation"}` too. They are futile too.

> How to resolve the issue??

here is our sample code.

```
lagrangian = 
  1/2 (1 + r[t]^2/
     l^2 - (2 Sqrt[2] (1 + 1/l^2) r[t]^2)/(1 + r[t]^2)^(3/2) K^2 + 
     1/(1 + r[t]^2/l^2 - (2 Sqrt[2] (1 + 1/l^2) r[t]^2)/(1 + r[t]^2)^(
       3/2)) r'[t]^2 + r[t]^2 L^2);

eulerLagrange[lagrangian_, vars_, dvars_] := 
  Thread[(Table[D[D[lagrangian, dvar], t], {dvar, dvars}] - 
      Table[D[lagrangian, var], {var, vars}]) == 
    ConstantArray[0, Length@vars]];

equationsOfMotion = 
 eulerLagrange[lagrangian, {r[t]}, {r'[t]}] /. l -> 1 // Simplify

tmax = 1000; K = 1; L = 20;
sol = NDSolve[{equationsOfMotion, r[0] == 1.5, r'[0] == 1.5}, {r[t], 
   r'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{r[t], r'[t]}] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: It's probably not [stiffness](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39028/understanding-ndsolvendsz/237989#237989) since `r'[t]` $\sim$ `r[t]^2` near the end of integration. That is, $r(t) \sim K/(t-t_1)$, which would be a singularity instead of stiffness. A singularity is usually a feature, not a problem. If you think you have a reason that there should be no singularities, then the problem might be a mistake in modeling (setting up the DEs). Note the singularity persists if we use `WorkingPrecision -> 32`. That means it is less likely to be a numerical issue.